# Adding combined footage to points from the beginning of a line

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geometry

I'm trying to add the footage of each point from the beginning of the line to the end.  There are around 4k vertexes between the two ends that I need to put the footage from the beginning of the line and adds footage as it goes down the line.

An example would be three points total with 50 ft between them.  The first point would be 0, the second point 50 and the third point 100 (that's just an example).  Is there a way to do this?

I was going to break the line into segments based of vertexes to get the individual length of each segment. How would I have it add going down the line and add that combined footage to each point?  I have arc 10.1, but am open to any solution/ideas.

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGIS, you can you the linear referencing tools for this. create one fields with the length in feet, and use this fields to [create routes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003m00000005000000). Then you can use [locate feature along route](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Locate_Features_Along_Routes/003m00000007000000/) to extract the footage of each point.

Comment: This is the ArcGIS solution, but he doesn't have points yet - just the route line. And based on other questions, his license level is not sufficient to run Feature Vertices to Points. ET Geotools has a tool for this, but I don't know if that's an option - the demo could only handle 100 points at a time. Is there another way he could get points *at the vertices* in ArcGIS you could edit into your answer? @joebob the other alternative would be to create the points in QGIS for use in ArcGIS.

Comment: GME (http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/gmecommands.htm) can do it (line to point vertices) as well in order to stay in ArcGIS environment. Otherwise you need arcpy script and of course in QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to do the job and it is not important to use just QGIS or arcgis, OpenJUMP 1.7.0 Plus has linear referencing tool which is very simple to use.

Open the tool

[image: Location of the linear referencing tools]

Fill in the parameters

[image: Settings of the linear referencing tool]

Result is a point layer with distances as an attribute

[image: Output layer labeled with distances]

Comment: I noticed that I did not answer to your question. You want to measure the distances to existing vertices, right? I can delete my answer in that case as invalid.

Comment: Yeah, there aren't consistent numbers.  I was just using 50 as an example.

Comment: Ok, I believe I can do it with Spatialite. Is it an acceptable tool for you?

Comment: Is there a way to do it on MS SQL 2008?

Answer (score 0):

If 'open to any solution/ideas', then you can also do it using postGIS database and window functions. If you're interested in this solution please comment my answer so I could prepare few queries for you.